# Comparing chars in if statement with or

Tags: c++

recently I encountered a problem with comparing chars.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string test1 = "test";
    string test2 = "adssadad";
    if (test1[0] == 'b' || 'd')
    {
        cout << "it equals" << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Everytime I compare chars in if statement and or appears - if statement always returns true and code inside is executed. How do I solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
if (test1[0] == 'b' || 'd')
```

is equivalent to

```
if ((test1[0] == 'b') || 'd')
```

due to `==` having higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `||`. This always evaluates to `true` since `'d'` implicitly evaluates to `true`.

Probably what you thought this meant was

```
if (test1[0] == ('b' || 'd'))
```

but this wouldn't work either since this will evaluate to

```
if (test1[0] == true) // <=> if (test1[0])
```

Which will be true whenever `test[0] != '\0'`. What you need is to test each case separately

```
if ((test1[0] == 'b') || (test1[0] == 'd'))
```

If there are lots of values to check then it may be easier to store them in a container and use an algorithm.

```
const std::vector<char> vals {'b', 'd'};
if (std::find(vals.cbegin(), vals.cend(), test1[0]) != vals.cend())
```

Answer (score 2):

'd' evaluates to non-zero, which is interpreted as `true` in C++. If even one operand of OR is true, the entire expression is true, so the `cout` line is executed.

You want to write `test[0] == 'b' || test[0] == 'd'`

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is interpreted as follows: `if [(test1[0] == 'b') || ('d')]` Since 'd' is not null or zero, it always evaluates to true.
Change the statement to `if (test1[0] == 'b' || test1[0] = 'd')`

Answer (score -2):

Use switch here:

```
switch(test[10])
{
 case b:
 case d:
   cout << "it equals" << "\n";
 break;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure a switch statement improves functionality or readability here. This issue with the original code is in the formatting of the if statement.